# iPhone app crashes after update to iOS 14.2

Tags: support, bug, iphone

After updating to iOS 14.2 it’s not possible to open the iPhone app anymore. The app crashes right after the start on an [iPhone XS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_XS).

Stack Exchange didn’t seem too eager updating the app in the past. But this is really more than a convenience feature.

Comment: The application is no longer being developed and hasn’t been for awhile

Comment: It’s still the official app available on the App Store. If it’s not maintained anymore the app should be removed to clarify its status.

Comment: I can only assume they wait until the responsive design, which gives full support for any screen or device, is complete. Then they'll remove any trace of the mobile theme (what you get when browsing via a browser on mobile device) and the apps.

Comment: I was under the assumption the sof-team thinks the current mobile versions are already "done". I'm wondering when they will notice that a nice looking mobile page is no suitable replacement for even a basic app (notifications, banners, keyboard customizations all missing, just to name a few)

Comment: @dpr Done? It is more likely it has something to do with [the November 2017 mass layoff](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7926678#7926678) (a taboo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to uninstall and install the app again to make it start after the update.

The development status of the app, however, is very disappointing.